# How to Replace Hash Match (Partial Aggregate) with Stream Aggregate

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

My execution plan shows a hash match (partial aggregate) instead of a stream aggregate even though I have a non-clustered index (which basically means sorting is already in place). It gives me a suggestion to create another non-clustered index. I do not want to create another index as the table has high I/O. 
How do I convert the hash match into a stream aggregate?

Answer (score 2):

Not a lot of information here, but to directly answer the question that was asked: you can use the `ORDER GROUP` query hint. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017):

> { HASH | ORDER } GROUP
>
> Specifies that aggregations described in the
>   GROUP BY, or DISTINCT clause of the query should use hashing or
>   ordering.

That query hint may help you verify that a stream aggregate is a better choice than the hash aggregate. A few things to keep in mind are that it applies to the whole plan and it will continue to take effect even if there's an index change which means that an explicit sort is required.